# Trying to login to ECR fails with -no-include-email error

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

I am using this command to login to docker on my EC2

`$(aws ecr get-login --registry-ids xxxxxxx --region us-west-1 --no-include-email)`

when I do that, I get following error:

`Unknown options: --no-include-email`

what am I missing?

Comment: What version? `aws --version`

Comment: Same happened to me, the answer of the update using pip3 worked like a charm.

Comment: tl/dr; `get-login` was deprecated in favor of [get-login-password](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecr/get-login-password.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be using an older version of the CLI tools. Using a newer version of docker (17.09) and aws-cli (1.11.117 & 1.11.173) I don't receive this error

See the note here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ECR_AWSCLI.html#AWSCLI_get-login

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login.html

`pip install --upgrade --user awscli`

You may need to use `pip3` or `pip2` if you're using homebrew

Answer (score 31):

Above description is correct, steps are here:

1. `sudo apt install awscli`
2. `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`
3. `sudo pip3 install --upgrade awscli`

Reference: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2676

Comment: This should be the best answer.

Comment: it works. Using the pip method  will give me the version "aws-cli/1.18.25 Python/3.7.1 Windows/10 botocore/1.15.25”   , this version works

Answer (score 22):

The answer is already given, but it does not work **aws-cli v2**, so posting as an answer may help other

```
$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2)
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:
```

To get login token with **aws-cli V2** you can try

```
aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/reponame
```

To install AWS-CLI V2 you can check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html)

```
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
```

Comment: I got the `/usr/bin/bash: line 111: docker: command not found` error

Comment: You need to install docker @Mehmet

Comment: I thought I was working in a Docker-installed environment. My fault, sorry

Comment: I have aws-cli/2.2.22 and it doesn't need the /<reponame> at the end.  So for me this worked (changed account number of course) `aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-2 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`

Answer (score 8):

Try this for `awscli` v2 (But still worked on `1.9.0`)

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region ap-northeast-1 --profile your-profile | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <the_id>.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/<repo_name>
```

You can change:

- The `region`
- The `profile` if you config multi AWS profile on your machine.
- The `the_id` is a number like `12314311400`
- The `repo_name` eg: `my-api-repo`

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below steps. It worked for me.

1. aws ecr get-login

   The resulting output is a docker login command that you can use to authenticate your Docker client to your ECR registry.

   **Sample output:** docker login -u AWS -p [**your-password**] -e none https:// [**your-aws_account_id**].dkr.ecr.[**your-region**].amazonaws.com
2. Then remove "-e none" from the above output and Run the remaining command.

You will get be able to login successfully.